# Approaching Compact Sets of the Euclidean Space with the Product Topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

I was working on Croom's Principles of Topology with the product topology; and came across this problem:

> Knowing that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, use product space ideas to prove the same characterization of the compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Thus I'm supposed to show that a subset $A:=\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. And sadly I am completely lost. I think I could "decompose" $A$ into each coordinate spaces, and work on $A_i$ to find out the properties for $\mathbb R^n$. However I can't see any way to do so.

Croom uses the box topology for the term "product topology" for finite product spaces, but it doesn't really matter since I'm working on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: No, you’re to show that an **arbitrary** subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded; you can’t limit yourself to sets that are products.

Comment: Then I have even less ideas to work with. Could I work with unions of products?

Comment: Do you already have available the fact that the product of compact spaces is compact?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I do.

Comment: The fact that a compact set in a metric space is closed is a general result that follows from the definition of compactness, as is the fact that a compact set is bounded, so the question is really about the other direction, i.e., showing that a closed, bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact. If $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is bounded, show that there are closed, bounded sets $A_k\subseteq\Bbb R$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ such that $A\subseteq\prod_{k=1}^nA_k$. Then use the fact that $A$ is a closed subset of a compact set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, turns out that I was working on the other direction. But come to think of it, it's the direction that you mentioned that needed a new proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $A \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is compact, it is closed and bounded: this is true in any metric space (the first even for just Hausdorff spaces, for the second consider the  cover by sets $B(a,n), n \in \Bbb N$ for some $a \in A$, which has a finite subcover etc.). If we start by assuming $A$ is closed and bounded we can find closed intervals $A_1,\ldots A_n \subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $A \subseteq \prod_{i=1}^n A_i$. The $A_i$ are compact by what we know about $\Bbb R$, and so Tychonoff tells us that $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ is compact and hence so is $A$, being a closed subspace of it. Hence the equivalence.